# Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, where $p$ is prime. Show that if $G$ is not cyclic, then $G$ has at least $p+1$ maximal subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

Question: Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, where $p$ is prime.  Show that if $G$ is not cyclic, then $G$ has at least $p+1$ maximal subgroups.

I've seen this thread: [Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group with has more than one maximal subgroup. Prove that $G$ has at least $p+1$ maximal subgroups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626744/let-g-be-a-finite-p-group-with-has-more-than-one-maximal-subgroup-prove-tha) but I wasn't sure that if the condition "more than one maximal subgroup" could replace "$G$ is not cyclic".   So....

Let $|G|=p^n$, for prime $p$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Since $G$ is not cyclic, there does not exist $g\in G$ such that $g^n=1$.  Therefore, every element belongs to a maximal subgroup, so $G=\cup M$, where $M$ is a maximal subgroup (just taking the union of all maximal subgroups).  Now, $|M|=p^{n-1}$, since $G$ is a $p$-group.  Suppose there exist at most $p$ maximal subgroups.  So, I now want to add up the orders of all the maximal subgroups and show that it is less than $|G|$.  That is, we have $p^{n-1}+p^{n-1}-1+\dots+p^{n-1}-p$... but I am not getting the contradiction that I want.  Can anyone help me fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39941/finite-groups-with-exactly-one-maximal-subgroup?rq=1)

Comment: @CalvinLin Not quite.  I wasn't able to use it to help complete my argument.....

Comment: 1) It wasn't clear to me that you wanted someone to complete your argument. You could pull out that part to highlight it (I just skimmed it as the end of your writeup, as opposed to your main ask) $\quad$2)  Your argument seems almost complete to me. Show that $ p^n |G|  = |\cup M | \geq K(p^{n-1} -1 ) +1 $, so $ K  > p$, where $K$ is the number of maximal subgroups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have only $p$ subgroups of order at most $p^{n-1}$, because each of them has the group identity as a common element, their union can only have size at most $1+p(p^{n-1}-1) = p^n-p+1 \lt p^n$.  But you have already shown that every element of $G$ must be in some maximal subgroup, so the union must have size $p^n$.  That's a contradiction, so there must be at least $p+1$ maximal subgroups.

Comment: Thank you!  Your $1+p(p-1)^{n-1}$ is made up from: the "$1+$" from the id. element they all share, but what algebra is leading to $p(p-1)^{n-1}$?  I can't get my algebra to show that...

Comment: That's because I made a mistake.  Corrected now.

Comment: Ah, perfect!  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof.

Step  1. Prove it for the direct product $C_p\times C_p$ (find its subgroups of order $p$)

Step 2. Prove that if $f$ is a surjective homomorphism $G_1\to G_2$ then the number of maximal subgroups of $G_2$ is not bigger than the number of maximal subgroups of $G_1$ (the preimage of a maximal subgroup is a maximal subgroup).

Step 3. If $G$ is a non-trivial $p$-group then its center is non-trivial and contains a subgroup $C$ of order $p$. $C$ is normal in $G$.

Step 4.If $G/C$ is not cyclic then it has at least $p+1$ maximal subgroups. By 2. The same is true for $G$.

Step 5. If $G/C$ is cyclic then $G$ is Abelian.

Step 6. By the description of finite Abelian groups $G$ is a direct product of cyclic groups of orders $p^{k_1},...,p^{k_s}$ where $s>1$. Then $G$ has a homomorphism onto $C_p\times C_p$ and one can use 1 and 2.

Comment: It seems to me that similar reasoning allows us to prove that the number of maximal subgroups in a group of order $p^n$ is $(p^n-1)/(p-1)$

Comment: @kabenyuk this is correct.

Comment: @kabenyuk very nice observation! I did not know that :)  Thank you